# How to get raw JSON data using Struts2 Ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am getting `[object Object]` response in console while I expect a full JSON.

As per my action class :

```
public String getDensityData(){
    SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) ctx.getAttribute("SessionFactory");
    ProductDAO product = new ProductDAOImpl(sf);
    List<DensityGroup> densityList = product.getDensity();
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      densityjson = gson.toJson(densityList);
      System.out.println("JSON: "+densityjson);
    return "success";
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <action name="getJSON" class="com.bmm.action.ProductAction" method="getDensityData">
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">densityjson</param>
        <result name="success" type="json">/product_master.jsp</result>
</action>  
</package>
```

JSP:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<s:url namespace="/" action="getJSON"/>',
    data: "json",
    success: function(data){
    console.log(""+data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to get JSON from the response, you should specify a `dataType` property. JSON is a javascript `Object`, if you need to print it use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '<s:url namespace="/" action="getJSON"/>',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```