# How to fetch data from json objects and iterate values and display them in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm new to programming. I have been working with struts2 and I have action class method which returns json data, which is an array of nested objects.
I want to fetch this data and iterate through it and display it on a jsp page. Can anyone help me how do do that

Comment: Similar like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42937198/573032) answer.

Answer (score 0):

In JSP, use JSTL to iterate over it your array of objects. Below example assumes you get an Array of `persons` with each object having a `name` and `address` field:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<table>
 <c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person">
    <tr>
        <td>${person.name}</td>
        <td>${person.address}</td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Another option is to implement a doGet method in servlet and inside your JSP call that API via Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('<table/>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
  $.getJSON('url/to/servlet', function(persons) {
    persons.each(function(i, person) {
        $('<tr/>').appendTo(table)
            .append($('<td/>').text(person.name))
            .append($('<td/>').text(person.address));
    });
  });
});
```